# Is it possible to change the vertical position of cancel button in the search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I moved the search bar from `UIView` to `navigationItem` in `UIViewController` when I was updating the application from 10 to 11 iOS SDK. 
Further, I set to position a background image in `UISearchBar` with a vertical offset because the distance between the logo and searchBar was small.

[image: search is not active]

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(searchFieldImage, for: .normal)
searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
```

But I can't right be positioning the Cancel button on vertical. How can I set the vertical position the Cancel button in `UISearchBar`, or title in button?

[image: search is active]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the cancel button as follows:-

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
```

Now try to update the frame(y axis) of `cancelButton`.

Comment: Thank you!! It works, please update your answer with the swift example, and you can add cancelButton.setTitlePositionAdjustment method for more explaining answer

Comment: Could you please be more thorough with your explanation?

Answer (score 3):

```
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
let offset = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 7)
cancelButton.setTitlePositionAdjustment(offset, for: .default)
```

Also take a look at apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase searchBar Height `heightAnchor.constraint` to increase navigation Bar Height to fix image logo issue , check it

In IOS 11

```
searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```